# How to install python developer package?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

I am trying to get `mod_wsgi 3.3` to work. When I run `make` it is telling me that I am missing the Python developer package. How do I get and install the Python developer package?

The error I get is as follows:

```
mod_wsgi.c:135:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
mod_wsgi.c:138:2: error: #error Sorry, Python developer package does not appear to be installed.
mod_wsgi.c:142:2: error: #error Sorry, mod_wsgi requires at least Python 2.3.0 for Python 2.X.
mod_wsgi.c:150:2: error: #error Sorry, mod_wsgi requires that Python supporting thread.
mod_wsgi.c:153:21: error: compile.h: No such file or directory
mod_wsgi.c:154:18: error: node.h: No such file or directory
mod_wsgi.c:155:20: error: osdefs.h: No such file or directory
```

System (Amazon EC2 instance)

- Apache 2.2.16 (Unix)
- Amazon Linux(Red Hat 4.4.4-13) AMI Beta Version 2011.02
- Python 2.6.6

Comment: How did you install Python 2.6.6?

Comment: Yes it was installed into the operating system by default.

Comment: Sorry, I did not install it myself. Python 2.6.6 was already on the system when I created an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`yum install python-devel` will work.

If `yum` doesn't work then use

`apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: Ugh - I was searching for python*dev... Thank you.

Comment: Small not for future users, I was using a venv with python3.7 (non the default python3.8), i had to run `sudo apt install python3.7-dev`

Comment: You need to work with python3 now .

Answer (score 18):

If you use yum search you can find the python dev package for your version of python.

For me I was using python 3.5. I ran the following

```
yum search python | grep devel
```

Which returned the following

[image]

I was then able to install the correct package for my version of python with the following cmd.

```
sudo yum install python35u-devel.x86_64
```

This works on centos for ubuntu or debian you would need to use apt-get

Comment: Which version of python is the `python-devel.x86_64` package for?

Answer (score 12):

For me none of the packages mentioned above did help.

I finally managed to install `lxml` after running:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev` for python3.8

Comment: `Suggest edit queue is full` - everybody wants Python 3.8