# How to install python-dev on MSYS2?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, msys2

Posts I've viewed:
[How to Install Python Development Tools on MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784367/how-to-install-python-development-tools-on-msys2)

I'm trying to run pyinstaller in msys2, but I'm getting the following error:

```
OSError: Python library not found: 
    python38.dll, libpython3.8.dll, libpython38.dll, libpython3.8m.dll, libpython38m.dll
This would mean your Python installation doesn't come with proper library files.
This usually happens by missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of Python installation.

* On Debian/Ubuntu, you would need to install Python development packages
  * apt-get install python3-dev
  * apt-get install python-dev
* If you're building Python by yourself, please rebuild your Python with `--enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on Darwin)
```

Here's what I've tried installing in MSYS2 using pacman:

- mingw-w64-x86_64-python
- libgpgme-python
- mingw-w64-i686-python3
- base-devel

Unfortunately, I get the same error every time. I've also tried setting my path variable to every place I could think of that might have these libraries, and even one spot that I *know* has `libpython3.8.dll` but it was no help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like
`pip install python-dev-tools`
was what I was looking for.

Comment: This does nothing for me. I still get the same
OSError: Python library not found: python38.dll, libpython38.dll, libpython3.8.dll, libpython38m.dll, libpython3.8m.dll

When trying to run pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

Just some more detail - note that there is in fact a `python-devel` package in MSYS2 (and only there):

```
$ pacman -Ss 'python' | grep 'python-dev'
msys/python-devel 3.11.8-1
```

- https://packages.msys2.org/package/python-devel?repo=msys&variant=x86_64

... however, it seems it is just a "metapackage" - it does not have any header, etc files of its own:

```
$ wget https://mirror.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/python-devel-3.11.8-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
...
2024-03-23 02:53:46 (12.8 MB/s) - ‘python-devel-3.11.8-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst’ saved [2178/2178]

$ tar tf python-devel-3.11.8-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
.BUILDINFO
.MTREE
.PKGINFO
```

... even if the package description mentions "Python headers":

```
$ tar axf python-devel-3.11.8-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst .PKGINFO -O
# Generated by makepkg 6.0.2
pkgname = python-devel
pkgbase = python
pkgver = 3.11.8-1
pkgdesc = Python headers and dev dependencies
url = https://www.python.org/
builddate = 1707778846
packager = CI (msys2/msys2-autobuild/d4515ba2/7879011349)
size = 0
arch = x86_64
license = custom
depend = python=3.11.8
makedepend = libbz2-devel
makedepend = libxcrypt-devel
makedepend = libexpat-devel
makedepend = mpdecimal-devel
makedepend = libsqlite-devel
makedepend = libffi-devel
makedepend = ncurses-devel
makedepend = libreadline-devel
makedepend = liblzma-devel
makedepend = openssl-devel
makedepend = zlib-devel
makedepend = autotools
makedepend = autoconf-archive
makedepend = gcc
```

So, I'm not sure exactly what the utility of this package is - I could have done some builds, even without it installed ...