# error while checking gdb version: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.10.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, gdb, msys2

I am using MSYS2 and have installed all the gcc, g++ and gdb. gcc and g++ are working fine and I can check for the version. but while trying to check for gdb version:

```
$ gdb --version
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.10.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This shows up. I have tried reinstalling the package but the error remains. How do I solve this? (beginner so apologies for any mistakes)

Comment: While it seems like a GDB package dependency problem (and probably should be reported to the MSYS2 maintainers), as a possible workaround have you tried installing Python3 or other related packages?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784367/how-to-install-python-development-tools-on-msys2

Answer (score 0):

Installing Python 3 using the MSYS2 terminal solved the issue for me.

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python3
```