# How can I add python-dev package to requirements.txt?

Tags: python, requirements

I am trying add the `python-dev` package to my requirements.txt file, but I must be using the wrong package name. I have tried:

python3.7-dev

python-dev

py-dev

Comment: Requirements.txt is for python packages, you can't put an OS package in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install package at OS level you should seriously consider using a docker container to deploy/release your application.

Here is a snippet:

```
FROM python

RUN apt-get install python-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

...
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess there's great explanation about how to install it:

[How to install python developer package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230444/how-to-install-python-developer-package)

For it's installing you should use your operation system package manager, such as:
yum, dnf, apt-get, brew or kinda